# Is this a bug in top?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-snow-leopard, monitoring, process

This command line:

`top -l 3 -n 10 -o "vprvt"`

For some reason there are two processes that consistently creep up in the *second* sample's output regardless of their actual VPRVT size, and they do not show up in the first or third samples (or any further samples as it seems).

For instance, the first sample's output might be:

```
PID    USER          COMMAND          %CPU RSIZE  RPRVT  RSHRD  VPRVT  PPID
14899  hawk          WebProcess       0.0  2069M+ 1581M+ 40M+   2680M+ 14897
64     root          mds              0.0  60M+   51M+   8348K+ 880M+  1
14897  hawk          Safari           0.0  502M+  391M+  131M+  807M+  124
etc..
```

The second sample's output then begins with something like this:

```
PID    USER          COMMAND          %CPU RSIZE  RPRVT  RSHRD  VPRVT  PPID
15     root          DirectoryService 0.0  3780K  1052K- 936K-  -2M+   1
129    hawk          Dock             0.0  18M    5836K- 35M-   -19M+  124
14899  hawk          WebProcess       0.0  2069M+ 1581M+ 40M+   2680M+ 14897
etc..
```

..and the samples after that are very similar to the first sample's output.

When I run top in interactive mode using the same options then this oddity also happens, but only flashes briefly the second time that the screen updates.

The problem is that I can not use "-l 2" and pipe the output to a filter like that (I could increase the argument to the "-n" option and cut out the two odd lines but I would rather not).

Can anyone explain that or is it a bug?